# load data from csv to mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I am working on a small application that will load data from a csv file into the database. Right  now i encountered  an error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax
>   error near 'csv   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (A,B,C)' à la ligne 1

Here's the code

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testcsv","root","");
        Statement st = connect.createStatement();
        query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"+filename+"' INTO csv   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (A,B,C)";
        st.executeUpdate(query);
```

The variable filename is declared and assigned a value from a jTextField which is the file path.
Also the variable connect is declared outside of the try-catch.

The user will browse for the file he wants to add to the database and from there i get the file path

Thank you

Comment: I think that you are missing "TABLE", your query should be `"LOAD DATA INFILE '"+filename+"' INTO TABLE csv   FIELDS` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Also, you should try to translate error messages to english to improve the possibilities to get help.

Comment: Thank you RubioRic for the answer and the solution.I forgot "TABLE"

Comment: You're welcome. De rien. :-)